# i am new, program gives error "there are no type variables left in list"

Tags: typeerror

How the game works is that there is a 3-digit number, and you have to guess it. If you guess a digit in the right spot, you get a strike, and if you guess a digit but in the wrong spot you get a ball. I've coded it like this.

```
x = random.randint(1, 9) 
y = random.randint(1, 9)
z = random.randint(1, 9)
userguessunlisted = input('What number do you want to guess?')
numbertoguess = list[x, y, z] 

userguess = list(userguessunlisted)
b = 0
s = 0
while 0 == 0:
    if userguess[0] == numbertoguess[0]:
        s = s + 1
    if userguess[0] == numbertoguess[1]:
        b = b + 1
    if userguess[0] == numbertoguess[2]:
        b = b + 1
    if userguess[1] == numbertoguess[0]:
        b = b + 1
    if userguess[1] == numbertoguess[1]:
        s = s + 1
    if userguess[1] == numbertoguess[2]:
        b = b + 1
    if userguess[2] == numbertoguess[0]:
        b = b + 1
    if userguess[2] == numbertoguess[1]:
        b = b + 1
    if userguess[2] == numbertoguess[2]:
        s = s + 1
    print(s + "S", b + "B")
    if s != 3:
        b = 0
        s = 0
    else:
        print('you win!')
        break
```

Comment: One place in which I can see an issue is trying to concatenate a string and a number when you use your print statement. If you want to concatenate them, then you can use `print(str(s) + 'S')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you said `list[x, y, z]` on line 5, you used square brackets, which python interprets to be a [type annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). For example, if I wanted to specify that a variable is a `list` of `int`s, I could say

```py
my_list_of_ints: list[int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

I think what you meant to do is create a new list from `x`, `y`, and `z`. One way to do this is

```py
numbertoguess = list([x, y, z])
```

which is probably what you meant to write. This is valid because the [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function takes an [`iterable`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp) as its one and only argument.

However, the `list` portion is redundant; square brackets on the right-hand side of an assignment statement already means "create a list with this content," so instead you should simply say

```py
numbertoguess = [x, y, z]
```

A few other notes:

1. `input` will return a string, but you are comparing that string to integers further down, so none of the comparisons will ever be true. What you want to say is something like the following:

   ```
   while True:
       try:
           userguessunlisted = int(input('What number do you want to guess?'))
       except:
           continue
       break
   ```

   What this code does is attempts to parse the string returned from `input` into an `int`. If it fails to do so, which would happen if the user inputted something other than a valid integer, an [exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) would be thrown, and the `except` block would be entered. `continue` means go to the top of the loop, so the `input` line runs repeatedly until a valid `int` is entered. When that happens, the `except` block is skipped, so `break` runs, which means "exit the loop."
2. `userguessunlisted` is only ever going to contain 1 number as written, so `userguess` will be a list of length 1, and all of the comparisons using `userguess[1]` and `userguess[2]` will throw an [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError). Try to figure out how to wrap the code from (1) in another loop to gather multiple guesses from the user. Hint: use a [`for`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) loop with [`range`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp).

   It might also be that you meant for the user to input a 3-digit number all at once. In that case, you can use a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to grab each character from the input and parse it into a separate `int`. This is probably a bit complicated for a beginner, so I'll help you out:

   ```
   [int(char) for char in input('What number do you want to guess?')]
   ```
3. `print(s + "S", b + "B")` will throw [`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError). There are lots of ways to combine non-string types with strings, but the most modern way is using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). For example, to combine `s` with "S", you can say `f"{s}S"`.
4. When adding some amount to a variable, instead of saying e.g. `b = b + 1`, you can use the [`+=` operator](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-operator/) to more concisely say `b += 1`.
5. It's [idiomatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom#:%7E:text=A%20programming%20idiom%20or%20code,more%20programming%20languages%20or%20libraries.) in python to use [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for variables and [Pascal case](https://www.theserverside.com/definition/Pascal-case) for classes. So instead of writing e.g. `numbertoguess`, you should use `number_to_guess`. This makes your code more readable and familiar to other python programmers.

Happy coding!

Comment: tysm this really helped. I tried what you suggested, but I keep getting this weird int object is not iterable error. I posted my edited code. I think(?) it's because I tried listing something that I inted, though I'm not sure what that would do. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you've edited your post, but I think I can guess where you've gone wrong. As I mentioned above, the [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function takes one argument which must be an [iterable](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp). On the line `userguess = list(userguessunlisted)`, `userguessunlisted` must therefore be an iterable. However, if you used the code from (1) verbatim, it will be an `int`. You should instead say `userguess = [ userguessunlisted ]`.

Comment: By the way, the best way to say "thank you" on stack overflow is to accept the answer that helped you the most by ticking the check mark on the upper left-hand corner. This also helps future visitors with similar questions quickly determine which answers are the most useful. If you have any further questions, please edit your post and respond here and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you! I did and I ticked the check mark.